# Jquery UI dialog hides the parent in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI modal dialog with smoothness theme. It works fine except when I open the dialog, the parent window is covered with gray color. I cannot see the contents of the parent. When I close, it looks fine.

The same thing works fine in FF. Do I need to change any CSS for this?

Thanks.

> Edited to include Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Dialog Form',
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true         
    });
    function Opendialog() {
       $("#openDialog").dialog("open");
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to display the dialog? Can you verify if you have modal: true in your dialog options?

Comment: @Cybernate, I updated my post with the code. yes I am using modal: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifying modal:true in your options, the dialog will be displayed as modal (blocking dialog).
Either remove that option or set it to false.

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Dialog Form',
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: false
    });

    function Opendialog() {
        $("#openDialog").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it possible to just blur the parent window but still able to see the contents? modal:false, does not blur the parent though.

Comment: In that select a lighter theme for the ui or you can edit the jquery-ui.css and change the opacity attribute of .ui-widget-overlay class to something like 0.1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have modal set to true. Set it to false or roll you own theme.